# send the emails using my gmail account in python?

Tags: python-3.x, smtp, gmail

I m trying to send emails to my users through my Gmail account but it does not work although my Gmail login credentials are also correct but it gives an error

Here is the code for Email Sending!

```
            if request.method == 'POST':
                EmailAddress = request.form['Emails']
                Subject = request.form['Subject']
                Message = request.form['Message']
                EmailList = EmailAddress.split(',')
                Message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(Subject, Message)
                for EmailName in EmailList:
                    Server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
                    Server.ehlo()
                    Server.login(UserEmail, UserPassword)
                    Server.sendmail(UserEmail, EmailName.strip(), Message)
                    response = "Success"
                    Server.quit()
```

```
Error:-(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials t21sm2044741ejr.68 - gsmtp')
```

Comment: Does your gmail account have 2-factor authentication enabled?

Comment: i dont think so

Comment: Well, according to the support-page provided in the error message, you can try one of two things: 1) Create and use an **App Password** (instead of your gmail password) https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833 . 2) Set your gmail account to connections from **allow less-secure app** https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: less secure app are also on